# MSSQL Stored Procedure Creating A Temp Table Dynamically

Tags: sql-server

We're trying to write some automated reports to execute SQL statements we have stored in a table.  The table data is normally used in a stored procedure called by the triggers and uses data passed in via temp tables (created in the trigger statements), and has a table name, then an SQL statement that works on #TempInserted and #TempDeleted, which correspond to the Inserted and Deleted objects from the trigger and then some e-mail columns that determine where to send the output.

This all works fine from the trigger statements, as each creates each temp table once, during execution:-

```
SELECT * INTO #TempInserted FROM INSERTED
SELECT * INTO #TempDeleted FROM DELETED
```

Then the trigger calls the TriggerHandler stored procedure, passing the table name through as a pararmeter.

..

However, when I try to create these dynamically from a general stored procedure in order to fire off these statements as reports (so we don't duplicate the statements), in a batch, I'm hitting a problem:-

```
SELECT * INTO #TempInserted FROM ...
```

works fine from a defined table, or object (e.g. "FROM INSERTED"), but I've found that it can't get it's schema from a dynamic query.

For example, I can do

```
SELECT TOP 1 * INTO #Test FROM TableA 
SELECT * FROM #Test
DROP TABLE #Test
```

But I can't then do

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 1 * INTO #Test FROM TableA'
SELECT * FROM #Test
DROP TABLE #Test
```

because then #Test is local to the EXECUTE context, and not its parent.
I can, however, do the insert in the EXECUTE (or a stored procedure) because the temp table is in scope, if I've already created the table schema:-

```
SELECT * INTO #Test FROM TableA WHERE 1 = 2 -- create an empty schema
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO #Test SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TableA'
SELECT * FROM #Test
DROP TABLE #Test
```

So, that's OK, but my problem comes when I want to dynamically create that schema, depending on the table name were running the reports for.  The INSERT works:-

```
SELECT * INTO #Test FROM TableA WHERE 1 = 2 -- create an empty schema
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(20) = 'TableA'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(200) = N'INSERT INTO #Test SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + @Table
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
SELECT * FROM #Test
DROP TABLE #Test
```

But only if the temp table already has a schema.  If I try to conditionally create the schema, depending on the table selected, I get a parsing error:-

```
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(20) = 'TableA'
IF @Table = 'TableA'
    SELECT * INTO #Test FROM TableA WHERE 1 = 2 -- create an empty schema
IF @Table = 'TableB'
    SELECT * INTO #Test FROM TableB WHERE 1 = 2 -- create an empty schema

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(200) = N'INSERT INTO #Test SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ' + @Table
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
SELECT * FROM #Test
DROP TABLE #Test
```

gives "There is already an object named '#Test' in the database." - so the query parser isn't following the structure of the query, which only actually creates the temp table once.  This also holds true if you do

```
SELECT * INTO #Test FROM ....
DROP TABLE #Test
SELECT * INTO #Test FROM ....
```

So, is there a way in SQL Server 2012, of either being able to do

```
SELECT * INTO #Test FROM (dynamic SQL statement)
```

or to bypass the parser thinking you're creating the object twice

```
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(20) = 'TableA'
IF @Table = 'TableA'
    SELECT * INTO #Test FROM TableA WHERE 1 = 2 -- create an empty schema
IF @Table = 'TableB'
    SELECT * INTO #Test FROM TableB WHERE 1 = 2 -- create an empty schema
```

or to dynamically create the locally scoped temp table, from an existing database table's schema, where the table name is stored in a variable (all the examples I've found of this use the "SELECT * INTO #Test" code, which as I mentioned requires a statically defined object to create from)?

-------edit--------

For a bit of context, here's an example of why we're doing this:-
A trigger may fire producing a warning e-mail if a certain item type is transacted into a certain location.  This works with our current triggers.  The reason we're doing this is so that we can, in future, write a UI so the users can add other item types to this list themselves, rather than us having to update the trigger - this also means that we can control/validate the SQL being generated, behind the scenes of a point-and-click interface so that our users don't need to know any SQL and that we can be sure that nothing malicious or that will cause errors will be used.

We also can't do this in the BLL because it's from our ERP system and this would then mean we'd have to make changes to base objects, which is obviously undesirable if it can be avoided.

There is the potential for some of these e-mails to be missed/ignored/forgotten/not-actioned, so the users requested the same information on a periodic basis, as well as as-at the transaction occurring:-

So, next, we want to produce, for some of these trigger statements, daily/weekly/monthly reports.  Now, obviously, it would be ideal if we could use the existing SQL trigger statements we have set up as then if one were changed it would then automatically affect the periodical reports - stay DRY.  It would also mean that if we set up a new trigger, we could automatically include it in the reports by merely inserting a reference to the trigger code, along with the table name, frequency, etc, into the table that drives the periodical reports stored procedure.  Again, in future, we could then write a UI, so that users can then request and schedule these reports themselves, with no intervention required from us.

Comment: Couldn't you do the select * in the trigger already? At least it sounds like it would solve all your problems

Comment: We currently do the select * in the trigger, as I mentioned, but we're now trying to reuse those statements and group them up for scheduled reports, so we will CURSOR around a reports table, then create each #TempInserted and #TempDeleted based on a number of different tables, in turn, and this is where the problem lies.  For example, TableA and TableB s' triggers would each create those temp tables.  We want to loop around a table containing values of "TableA" and "TableB" and then go something like: get-table-name; exec SP using trigger; get next-table-name; loop. This is the problem

Comment: There's an answer to this but it is not pretty: Nested dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect I'm stuck in a catch-22 situation here.  However, I've found a way around it that isn't *too* messy.  I extract the item processing code into another stored procedure, and then compound execution of that onto the dynamic "SELECT INTO" statement - that way it runs in the same execution instance and thus has access to the temp table created in, and local to, that instance:-

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO #TestTable FROM ' + @Table + ' WHERE ' + @WhereClause
SET @SQL = @SQL + '; EXEC ReportProcess'
EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @SQL
```

the ReportProcess stored procedure then has access to the temporary table and can process it, accordingly